# How to find the dimensions of a rectangle given a) the area and the diagonal or b) the perimeter and the diagonal

Tags: geometry, rectangles

I need to write concise formulas of these two:$\space \space \space$
$(1)$ finding the dimensions of a rectangle given the Area and the diagonal
$\space \space \space$$(2)$ finding the dimensions of a rectangle given the Perimeter and the diagonal

Searching on google I can only find examples using number (eg. “Let’s assume the diagonal is $5$ and the area is $25$”etc) but I’m having trouble writing down formulas that use variables (so that I can use them in my code).

Would appreciate if someone could show me how to formulate the formulas (no pun intended) for these two.
Thank you!

Comment: Let use $a$, and $b$ for sides/dimensions, then area is $A=a \cdot b$, diagonal is $d=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, and perimeter is $P=2a+2b$. Are you able to proceed with this approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If you know the Diagonal and Area of a Rectangle, can you find the sides of the rectangle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3631995/if-you-know-the-diagonal-and-area-of-a-rectangle-can-you-find-the-sides-of-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the dimensions of rectangle be $a$ and 
$b$ and let the Area be $A$, perimeter be $P$ and the diagonal be $D$
$$A=ab$$
$$D=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
$$D^2=a^2+b^2$$
$$D^2=(a+b)^2-2ab=(a+b)^2-2A$$
$$a+b=\sqrt{D^2+2A}$$
Now $b=\dfrac{A}{a}$
$$a+\dfrac{A}{a}=\sqrt{D^2+2A}$$
$$a^2-a\sqrt{D^2+2A}+A=0$$
Now this is a quadratic equation in the form of $a$. Hence solving it gives
$$a=\dfrac{\sqrt{D^2+2A}\space\pm\sqrt{D^2+2A-4A}}{2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{D^2+2A}\space\pm\sqrt{D^2-2A}}{2}$$
$$b=\dfrac{2A}{\sqrt{D^2+2A}\space\pm\sqrt{D^2-2A}}$$
The perimeter method
$$P=2(a+b)$$
$$b=\dfrac{P-2a}{2}$$
$$D^2=a^2+b^2=a^2+\Big(\dfrac{P-2a}{2}\Big)^2$$
$$8a^2-4aP-4D^2+P^2=0$$
Now this is a quadratic equation in the form of $a$. Hence solving it gives
$$a=\dfrac{P\pm \sqrt{8D^2-P^2}}{4}$$
$$b=\dfrac{P\mp \sqrt{8D^2-P^2}}{4}$$

Comment: Hey could you please explain how you get from
82−4−42+ to the final a = P +- square root of 8D2 -P2 /2

Comment: As this is a quadratic expression in the form of a, i used the quadratic formula $x=\dfrac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4fc}}{2a}$ here $x$ being $a$, $f$ (the coefficient of $a^2$) being $8$, $b$ (the coefficient of $a$) being $-4P$ and $c$ (the constant term) being $P^2-4D^2$

Comment: Oh okay, thank you, also one last question, how come that in the diagonal and area method there are two different answers for a and b, shouldn’t they both be equal? Because in the end we should get a = x, b=y and a=y, b=x, right?

Comment: If you rationalise $$b=\dfrac{(2A)(\sqrt{D^2+2A}\mp \sqrt{D^2-2A})}{(\sqrt{D^2+2A}\pm \sqrt{D^2-2A})(\sqrt{D^2+2A}\mp \sqrt{D^2-2A}) }$$$$b=\dfrac{2A(\sqrt{D^2+2A}\mp \sqrt{D^2-2A})}{4A}$$$$b=\dfrac{(\sqrt{D^2+2A}\mp \sqrt{D^2-2A})}{2}$$

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for your help!